# Listview not displaying properly

Tags: android, listview

I am having a problem with my listview, if there is something with a long name it creates a huge gap between list items. the view should display a name and date

[image: listview]

as you can see there is a huge space after `monthly event` and the date is missing, why is it doing that?

listview xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content">
<TextView android:text="@+id/calendarEntryText"
          android:id="@+id/calendarEntryText"
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:padding="10dp"
          android:textSize="25sp"/>
<TextView android:text="@+id/dateEntryText"
          android:id="@+id/dateEntryText"
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:padding="15dp"
          android:textSize="20sp"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can tell you about the missing part, it's because you are using horizontal linear layout and it's first child is occupying the whole width of the parent. so there is not place for the second child. I suggest you to use relative layout. HTH.